# Check a box based on last Monday of the month?

Tags: 2013, date-time

Is it possible to have a check box automatically tick based on a date if that date is the last Monday of a month? How would one accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a calculated field, returned as a Yes/No field. This isn't the full syntax, but something similar to this?

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date]), 0, IF(AND(Day([Date]) <= 7, Weekday([Date]) = 2 ), 1, 0))
```

If it's blank, unchecked.
If the day is less than 7 and it's a Monday, it's the first Monday of the month.

Sigh, you meant last Monday of the month. Maybe changing the above to `Day([Date]) >= 25` will be close enough?